# Ruby - use mutated array for next iteration in loop

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given the following arrays:

```
arr1 = [
  { nested_test1: [1,2] },
  { nested_test2: [true, false] }
]
arr2 = [
  { test1: 'a', test2: 'b' }
]
```

I wanna loop over array `arr2` and mutate it depending on the contents of `arr1`. The final result should look like this:

```
res_arr = [
  { test1: 'a', test2: 'b', nested_test1: 1, nested_test2: true },
  { test1: 'a', test2: 'b', nested_test1: 2, nested_test2: true },
  { test1: 'a', test2: 'b', nested_test1: 1, nested_test2: false },
  { test1: 'a', test2: 'b', nested_test1: 2, nested_test2: false },
]
```

So my initial setup looks like this:

```
res_arr = []
arr1.each do |hash1|
  arr2.each do |hash2|
    hash1.values.first.each do |value|
      hash2[hash1.keys.first] = value
      res_arr << hash2.clone
    end
  end
end
```

But this gives me the following:

```
res_arr = [
  {:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b", :nested_test1=>1},
  {:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b", :nested_test1=>2},
  {:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b", :nested_test1=>2, :nested_test2=>true},
  {:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b", :nested_test1=>2, :nested_test2=>false}
]
```

So what I wanna do then, is to use the mutated version for each iteration of `arr2`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: “Loop over array `arr2`” suggests that that array may contain more than one element. One can guess what the desired return value might be In the general case, but it is not made clear by your example. I suggest you add a second element to `arr2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

The following method permits its arguments to be arrays of arbitrary size.

```
def expand(arr1, arr2)
    arr2.product(
      arr1.map { |h| h.flatten.then { |k,v| v.map { |e| { k=>e } } } }.
           then { |first, *rest| first.product(*rest) }
    ).map { |first, (*rest)| first.merge(*rest.flatten) }
end
```

**Example**

```
arr1 = [{ nested_test1: [1,2] }, { nested_test2: [true, false] }]
arr2 = [{ test1: 'a', test2: 'b' }, { test3: 'c', test4: 'd' }]
```

```
expand(arr1, arr2)
  #=> [{:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b", :nested_test1=>1, :nested_test2=>true},
  #    {:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b", :nested_test1=>1, :nested_test2=>false},
  #    {:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b", :nested_test1=>2, :nested_test2=>true},
  #    {:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b", :nested_test1=>2, :nested_test2=>false},
  #    {:test3=>"c", :test4=>"d", :nested_test1=>1, :nested_test2=>true},
  #    {:test3=>"c", :test4=>"d", :nested_test1=>1, :nested_test2=>false},
  #    {:test3=>"c", :test4=>"d", :nested_test1=>2, :nested_test2=>true},
  #    {:test3=>"c", :test4=>"d", :nested_test1=>2, :nested_test2=>false}]
```

**Explanation**

The following steps are performed for the example.

Noting that:

```
arr1.map(&:flatten)
  #=> [[:nested_test1, [1, 2]], [:nested_test2, [true, false]]]
```

the first step is the following:

```
a = arr1.map { |h| h.flatten.then { |k,v| v.map { |e| { k=>e } } }
  #=> [[{:nested_test1=>1}, {:nested_test1=>2}],
  #    [{:nested_test2=>true}, {:nested_test2=>false}]]
```

See [Hash#flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-flatten) and [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-then). The latter method made its debut in Ruby v2.6. It is an alias of `Object#yield_self`, which was new in v2.5.

Then:

```
b = a.then { |first, *rest| first.product(*rest) }
  #=> [[{:nested_test1=>1}, {:nested_test2=>true}],
  #    [{:nested_test1=>1}, {:nested_test2=>false}],
  #    [{:nested_test1=>2}, {:nested_test2=>true}],
  #    [{:nested_test1=>2}, {:nested_test2=>false}]]
```

See Array#product. Here and especially below I made heavy use of [Array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). See also [this article](https://riptutorial.com/ruby/example/8798/decomposition).

Continuing,

```
c = arr2.product(b)
  #=> [[{:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b"}, [{:nested_test1=>1}, {:nested_test2=>true}]],
  #    [{:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b"}, [{:nested_test1=>1}, {:nested_test2=>false}]],
  #    [{:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b"}, [{:nested_test1=>2}, {:nested_test2=>true}]],
  #    [{:test1=>"a", :test2=>"b"}, [{:nested_test1=>2}, {:nested_test2=>false}]],
  #    [{:test3=>"c", :test4=>"d"}, [{:nested_test1=>1}, {:nested_test2=>true}]],
  #    [{:test3=>"c", :test4=>"d"}, [{:nested_test1=>1}, {:nested_test2=>false}]],
  #    [{:test3=>"c", :test4=>"d"}, [{:nested_test1=>2}, {:nested_test2=>true}]],
  #    [{:test3=>"c", :test4=>"d"}, [{:nested_test1=>2}, {:nested_test2=>false}]]]
```

and lastly:

```
c.map { |first, (*rest)| first.merge(*rest.flatten) }
  #=> <as shown above>
```

See [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what your goal here is. For instance, in `arr2`, can values of the hash be arrays? In `arr1` can the hashes have more than one key value pair? Or what happens if `arr2` has multiple hashes in it? Are they merged, or is the result expanded further somehow?

So it's hard to say exactly what the best course is.

Nonetheless, given the data you've given us and the result you say you want, you can get it like this using *Array#product*:

```
m = arr1.inject(&:merge)
m.values[0].product(m.values[1]).map {|a| Hash[m.keys.zip(a)].merge(arr2[0]) }
```

The intuition here is that I think you're trying to create all possible combinations of a couple of arrays, to generate all possible test cases? Depending on what you're trying to do, a more natural way to store the data and get the result might be:

```
m = { 
  test1: ['a'], 
  test2: ['b'],
  nested_test1: [1, 2],
  nested_test2: [true, false]
}

m.values.inject(&:product).map {|v| Hash[m.keys.zip(v.flatten)] }
```

Comment: Works as I intended. Thank you so much!

Comment: This only works if `arr2` contains only one element. The OP wishes to "loop over `arr2`", suggesting that it may contain more than one element, despite the example. Moreover, if it were only contain one element there would be no point in making it an array.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, I agree. I just don't think we know without more information what they want to happen if the array contains multiple elements, so I provided the code for the example given. Your answer is a good guess, but not necessarily what they want (although given that they've accepted it, it probably was what they want)